# What does Johnny say if you've not completed Blistering Love prior to starting Nocturne Op55N1?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077, cyberpunk-2077-phantom-liberty

This question is about an option near the end of *Cyberpunk 2077*. There are certain side quests that, if completed, provide extra options to finishing the last quest. What does Johnny say if those side quests are not completed?

The detailed version below contains SPOILERS.

In [Nocturne Op55N1](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Nocturne_Op55N1), V has three basic options available:

> they can accept Hanako's offer, ask Rogue for help, or ask Panam for help. The latter two options are only possible if the side quests Blistering Love & Queen of the Highway have been completed, respectively.
>  
>  If you have completed both Blistering Love & Queen of the Highway, then immediately after talking to Hanako, Johnny argues that V should give him control, and that he will call Rogue for help storming Arasaka tower.

Does this dialogue change if Blistering Love is not completed? What if Queen of the Highway is also not completed? If the dialogue changes, how?

I'm curious if unlocking Who Wants to Live Forever (from the *Phantom Liberty* DLC) also has an impact on this dialogue.

What does Johnny say if you've not completed Blistering Love prior to starting Nocturne Op55N1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A video of this is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkndmYS1_l8).

The conversation is significantly shorter than otherwise. Johnny complains about working with Hanako (as one might have expected) and says that V will not be able to extract themselves if they go ahead. But he doesn't offer any alternatives, even if working with Arasaka is literally the only choice available (including on the rooftop of Misty's Esoterica).